# Using for-each over an array of Objects - "Integer[] array" - Why Does "for(int i : array)" Work?

Tags: java, arrays, object, foreach, primitive

Why does using a primitive data type work in the second "for-each" loop when I am looping over an array of objects. Is there a casting back to the primitive equivalent of the Integer object occurring behind the scenes?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class CodeTestingClass 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

     Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};

     Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), 1);

     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array) + "\n" );

  for(Integer i : array)
  {

   System.out.print(i);

  }

  System.out.print("\n");

  for(int i : array)
  {

   System.out.print(i);

  }  

    }
}
```

Comment: As others already said, your program uses autoboxing a lot. To make this visual I usually enable the "hidden autoboxing" warnings or enable the "syntax colorer" in Eclipse. This prevents many surprising situations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Roland. I am using JCreator Pro 4.50 at the moment - I don't know if such a feature is available, I'll have a look through the settings to see what's there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's auto-unboxing, that's all. There's no need for iterating over anything to demonstrate that:

```
Integer x = 10;
int y = x;
```

From the Java Language Specification, [section 5.1.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8):

> Unboxing conversion converts values of reference type to corresponding values of primitive type.

(There are a few more details there, but it's mostly just the list of conversions.)

[Section 5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2) calls out unboxing conversions as being available in the context of assignment conversions.

Answer (score 2):

It's because for the Java base types (`int`, `byte`, `short`, etc.), it performs "[autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)" and autounboxing.

> When you take the object out of the collection, you get the Integer that you put in; if you need an int, you must unbox the Integer using the intValue method. All of this boxing and unboxing is a pain, and clutters up your code. The autoboxing and unboxing feature automates the process, eliminating the pain and the clutter.